# If $g(s) = \int_0^{\infty}\left( f(t)-1\right)t^{s-1} dt$ and $f(t) = \frac{1}{t}f(\frac{1}{t})$ , then $g(s)=g(1-s)$ for all $s$

Tags: calculus

Let f be a very nice positive real valued-function and $g(s) =  \int_0^{\infty}\left( f(t)-1\right)t^{s-1} dt$ and $f(t) = \frac{1}{t}f(\frac{1}{t})  \hspace{7mm} (\text{  for all } t>0 )$

Then, show that $g(s)=g(1-s)$ for all $s$.

(* The 'very nice' means that we don't need to consider integrable, differentiable and  $ \int_0^{\infty}$ is also well-defined, f has a rapidly decaying at $\infty$ , etc...)

---

[My attempt]

First, I make the change of variable, $t \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ , $dt= -\frac{1}{x^2}dx$.

$$g(s) =  \int_0^{\infty}\left( f(t)-1\right)t^{s-1} dt = \int_0^{\infty}\left( f(\frac{1}{x})-1\right)x^{1-s} x^{-2}dx = \int_0^{\infty}\left( f(\frac{1}{x})-1\right)x^{-1-s}dx$$
$$ = \int_0^{\infty}\left( xf(x)-1\right)x^{-1-s}dx = \int_0^{\infty}\left( f(x)-x^{-1}\right)x^{-s}dx  $$

However, $$ g(1-s) =  \int_0^{\infty}\left( f(x)-1\right)x^{-s} dx$$

I'm stuck here. How to solve this ?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: This is not true as the statement is equivalent to ${\cal M}[f(x)-1/x]={\cal M}[f(x)-1]$ where $\cal M$ denotes the Mellin transform.

Comment: If you still want to see some cancellations happen, split the integrals defining g(s) and g(1-s) at x=1.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire , Thank you but may I ask you something? 
Is it false even if I use this condition $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}f(\frac{1}{t})$ ?

Comment: @AsemAbdelraouf , Thank you, Could you explain in more detail? I don't understand "split the integrals defining $g(s)$ and $g(1-s)$ at $x=1$", sorry.

Comment: No worries. I will type it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments: This is false, to see why:
$$g(s) =  \int_0^{\infty}\left( f(t)-1\right)t^{s-1} dt = \int_0^{1}\left( f(t)-1\right)t^{s-1} dt  +\int_1^{\infty}\left( f(t)-1\right)t^{s-1}dt .$$

1. Make the subsitutiong $t\mapsto 1/t$ in the second intgeral.
2. Use the functional equation of $f.$
3. Repeat for $g(1-s).$
4. Compute $g(1-s) - g(s).$

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much!!